# Borland C++ Builder 5.0

Tags: ide, c++builder-5

Where can I get Borland C++ Builder 5.0 trial?

I've tried to google that, but it is so hard to find a proper legal link :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ Builder 5.0 was released in 1996 and superseded in 1997. I suspect the closest legal trial of a recent product you'll find is C++Builder XE3 from Embarcadero that took over the Borland products:

http://www.embarcadero.com/products/cbuilder

Or if Builder 5.5 is suitable try here:

https://downloads.embarcadero.com/free/c_builder

Comment: Yep, I tried that and it looks like that doesn't work for me. I have very old project that I need to rewrite to .net (it was written in Borland Builder C++ 5.0) - I'd like to be able to run and it and maybe debug. Any ideas?

Comment: I've just updated my answer with another possible solution, hope it helps.

Comment: That's not what I desired, but at least something. Thanks!

Comment: "Builder 5.5" is not a thing . Borland C++ 5.5 is a compiler without IDE.